# React: get element attribute from method

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript

I have this div:

```
<div className="item #{ @test() }" data-value="1">
```

and whant get access in method to data-attribute:

```
test: ->
 console.log ($(this).data("value"))
```

But I get this instead of element:

```
Constructor {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}
```

Comment: In your code you have a mistake. When you call some function in className attribute, object `this` referred to your React component, but not to rendered element.

Comment: @steppefox That's true, but the real mistake here is that you don't ever need to access the attributes of a rendered element when you're using React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't treat your DOM nodes as a source of truth.

The shape of a DOM node in React should always be *derived* from the data passed into a component via props, or maintained as part of its internal state.

Suppose that the render method for the component that renders that tag looks like this:

```
return (
  <div className={`item ${this.test()}`} data-value="1"></div>
);
```

In this case we're hardcoding data-value attribute as `"1"`. That's not particularly useful, it's more likely that we'd use a value from the component's props.

```
const { value = 1 } = props;

return (
  <div className={`item ${this.test()}`} data-value={value}></div>
);
```

Now we can build the class name programatically using this value, rather than trying to hook into the DOM node to get it back out.

```
const { value = 1 } = props;
return (
  <div className={`item ${this.test(value)}` data-value={value}></div>
);
```